# Creating an Array or List to Count Values

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, arraylist

I want to Count the items in an associated array. I have written small piece of code but now I am thinking it will not work. What strategy should I use?

I have created a class

```
public class itemsList
{
     public string itemName;
     public int itemCount;
}
```

Calculation code is as follows (consider `items` in the following code an array)

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
     //this is pseudo, I want help in this
     if (itemsList.Contain("itemName", item)
          itemsList[item].itemCount++;
     else
          itemsList.Add(item, 1);
}
```

Please keep in mind this array has later to be changed to `json` in the following format.

```
"apples": 10,
"oranges": 4
....
```

Comment: Check if `itemsList[item]` comes back with nothing. Then the key doesn't exist

Comment: @Fabjan I think this is best answer

Comment: @Fabjan let me try this, never used it before, I hope it will help

Comment: @Fabjan thanks alot for the help. Everthing is working like I wanted now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as already mentioned, `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` here is a better choice :

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, int> ItemsDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

Then all you need to do is:

```
string someItemName = "itemName";

if(!ItemsDict.ContainsKey(someItemName))
{
    ItemsDict.Add(someItemName, 1);
}
else 
{
    ItemsDict[someItemName]++;
}
```

Depending on what you need you might also want to use some class as a value:

```
public class itemsList
{
     public string itemName;
     public int itemCount;
}

...

private readonly Dictionary<string, itemsList> ItemsDict = new Dictionary<string, itemsList>();
// here we add an object
ItemsDict.Add(someItemName, myItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ `GroupBy` and create an anonymous class with properties `itemName` and `itemCount`. Each anonymous object stored inside the list `result` holds the item name and the count of the item.

```
var result = items.GroupBy(item => item)
                  .Select(group => new
                   {
                       itemName = group.Key,
                       itemCount = group.Count()
                   }).ToList();
```